# Toggling HTML text with a click or tap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing a website that will display long blocks of text which frequently contain unwieldy, difficult-to-read internal cross-references to other parts of the text.  For example, a passage in the original text might say:

"...as discussed in subparagraph (a) of subdivision (2) of chapter one thousand and fourteen of this article concerning modern art."

I would like to present this text to the reader in a more concise format, such as:

"...as discussed in Ch. 1014(2)(a) concerning modern art."

But I have to leave the user with the option to toggle between my abbreviated version and the original version.  I would like to accomplish this by letting the user click or tap on the particular text which will toggle between its abbreviated (by default) presentation and its full, original version.  Ideally, an abbreviated chunk of text would be highlighted or outlined in such a way as to signal to the user that a longer original passage was condensed for readability, but may be clicked/tapped to expand.

Can anybody suggest how I could program something like this?  Should/can it be done in HTML, CSS, jQuery, JavaScript, or something else?

(Just to be clear, I don't need an algorithm that will automatically transform the original text to a short form; I can manually identify and type the short forms in each case.)

Thank you!

Comment: if you are clicking it to toggle to the abbreviated text - how do want to get to the reference section you want?

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more clear about that -- I don't need to hyperlink the abbreviated text to the cross-referenced section.  For my particular application, there will not be much value in providing that functionality to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing relatively short snippets of text like a sentance I suggest storing the longer version in a `data-` attribute of a span tag `<span>`. Then use jQuery to swap out the text inside the span tag with the text stored in the `data-` attribute.

**HTML**

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce enim 
    nisl, elementum sit amet tortor eu, finibus tristique libero. Quisque 
    eget varius magna. Suspendisse sodales vitae ligula eget pellentesque. 
    <span data-long-text="Aenean pharetra ut massa non volutpat">Aenean 
    123</span>. Vivamus eu viverra eros. Aliquam condimentum lacus odio, 
    sit amet vulputate sem lacinia id. Suspendisse ultrices, lectus ut 
    volutpat cursus, justo risus aliquet lectus, hendrerit interdum massa 
    arcu at ipsum.
</p>
```

**CSS**

```css
span[data-long-text] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
// optional styling changed to long text
.long-text[data-long-text] {
    border-bottom-color: green;
}
```

**jQuery**

```js
$('[data-long-text]').on('click', function(e) {

    var $this = $(this);
    var short = $this.text(); // text in span tag
    var long  = $this.attr('data-long-text'); // text in data- attribute

    // text values swapping places
    $this.text(long);
    $this.attr('data-long-text', short);

    // optional styling change
    $this.toggleClass('long-text');

});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hp383q1t/

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/1gLv5qyv/

Use

```
$(".text-toggle").click(function(){
    $(".toggleAble").toggle();
});
```

Using the JQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a css class with property display:none use  for the text give it id and use the jquery method for toggle class

Answer (score 0):

This is more than possible with jQuery, CSS, and vanilla JS

HTML:

```
<p class="original">you original text</p>

<p class="secondary">secondary text</p>
```

CSS:

```
.secondary { display:none; }
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.original').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).hide();
    jQuery('.secondary').show();
});
```

Comment: I'm curious, why are you setting your `.secondary` paragraph to `display: inline`?

Comment: to change the display property from none, but the logical answer would have been to change back to the natural display of the element. haha. not sure why i choose inline.

Answer (score 0):

You would use html, css and jquery (javascript) like so:

...as discussed in subparagraph (a) of subdivision (2) of chapter one thousand 
         and fourteen of this article concerning modern art.

```css
a.ref {
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```js
$('.ref').click(function (e) {
    var refData = $(this).attr('data-att');
    var refText = $(this).text();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text(refData);
    $(this).attr('data-att', refText);
});
```

```js
$('.ref').click(function (e) {
    var refData = $(this).attr('data-att');
    var refText = $(this).text();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text(refData);
    $(this).attr('data-att', refText);
});
```

```css
a.ref {
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>...as discussed in <a href="#" class="ref" data-att="Ch. 1014(2)(a)">subparagraph (a) of subdivision (2) of chapter one thousand and fourteen</a> of this article concerning modern art.</p>
```

Comment: Why use an anchor tag? Seems a little uneccessary.

Answer (score 0):

If SEO isn't a consideration, I think I would approach it like so and store the long and short descriptions in a data attribute. With this running, you only have to focus on defining your HTML structure correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/skooliano/nyuroero/3/

**HTML**

```html
<p class="has-expanded-text">
     ...as discussed in <span class="toggle short" data-short-
     description="Ch. 1014(2)(a)" data-long-description="subparagraph 
     (a) of subdivision (2) of chapter one thousand and fourteen of this 
     article"></span> concerning modern art.
</p>
```

**CSS**

```css
.toggle { color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; }
```

**jQuery**

```js
$('p.has-expanded-text').each(function(index){
    var $span = $(this).find('.toggle'),
        $short = $span.data('short-description'),
        $long = $span.data('long-description');

    $span.text($short); // sets default text to short description

    $span.click(function(){
        if($span.hasClass('short')){
            $(this).addClass('long').removeClass('short');
            $(this).text($long);
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass('short').removeClass('long');
            $(this).text($short);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should include the rest of your example code in your answer, not just the jQuery.

Comment: Updated, although the rest of the code was provided in the fiddle. @hungerstar I think your example was much cleaner anyway.

Comment: The main reason a lot of us ask for all the code to be included in the answer is on the off chance jsFiddle (or similar) goes away the code in the fiddle gets deleted. Then we're left with a partial code example. Thanks for including the rest! Future visitors will thank you!